# How to fetch only selected mongo ids using spring data mongorepository method?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, mongorepository

I am trying this, it works for only one id at a time. I want to add list of ids.

```
public interface collectionRepository extends MongoRepository<collection, String> {
    
    List<collection> findByIds(List<UUID> id);
}
```

Could anyone suggest some ideas?Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Why don't you use `findAllById` ?

Comment: Findallbyid works when I am passing one id  or selecting all ids. I need only certain ids. I have a query template where I have to give a syntax to fetch ids from Mongo. Was looking for syntax where i can add list of ids at once.  My Template look like this: @JsonPropertyOrder(
{ "queryname", "collection", "field","datatype","startvalue"})
public class QueryModel1 {
 @JsonProperty("queryname")
 private String queryname;
 @JsonProperty("field")
 private String field;
 @JsonProperty("datatype")
 private String datatype;
 @JsonProperty("startvalue")
 private UUID startvalue;
}

Answer (score 0):

This works for a case where the POJO class is like:

```
public class User {

    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    // constructors (including default), get/set methods, etc.
}
```

And, the documents are stored in a collection `user` as, for example:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("604827bf8187ce707fb88681"), "firstName" : "John", "lastName" : "Doe", "_class" : "com.example.demo.User" }
```

The repository with the method to fetch the objects with the supplied list of ids:

```
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {

    @Aggregation(pipeline = { " { '$match': { '_id': { '$in':  ?0  } } }" } )
    List<User> findByIdsIn(List<String> ids);
}
```

The call to the repository method:

```
List<String> inputIds = Arrays.asList("604827d13de5773133374acc", "604827617a40155f5111b9ff");
List<User> outputList = userRepository.findByIdsIn(inputIds);
```

The `outputList` has the *two* documents matching the ids from the variable `inputIds`.

Comment: I was using Spring Data MongoDB v2.4 and MongoDB v4.2.