# Query for value or null in with Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I have a model with 'oficina' and 'marcaResolucion' fields. I need to query those which has the specified oficina AND those that have the following values in 'marcaResolucion': "PE", "" or null.

I have tried the following query but it's I'm getting more results than expected. Is there something wrong with this query?

```java
@Query("$and:" + 
       "        [" + 
       "         { oficina : ?0 }," + 
       "         { marcaResolucion: {$in: ?1} }" +
       "        ]")
List<OperacionPendiente> findByOficinaAndInMarcaResolucion(final String oficina, final List<String> marcaResolucion);
```

I am using resttemplate and don't want to change it if possible.

Comment: You can use the `$in` as shown in this post's answer: [How to fetch only selected mongo ids using spring data mongorepository method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66553047/how-to-fetch-only-selected-mongo-ids-using-spring-data-mongorepository-method/66557576#66557576)

Answer (score 1):

This variant should work:

```java
@Query("{ oficina : ?0, marcaResolucion: {$in: ?1} }")
List<OperacionPendiente> findByOficinaAndInMarcaResolucion(String oficina, List<String> marcaResolucion);
```

You'd invoke it with `findByOficinaAndInMarcaResolucion2("some oficina", asList("PE", null))`.

If you really only want to check for a single `marcaResolucion` you can use the following method definition:

```java
@Query("{ oficina : ?0, marcaResolucion: {$in: [?1, null]} }")
List<OperacionPendiente> findByOficinaAndInMarcaResolucion2(String oficina, String marcaResolucion);
```

You'd invoke it with `findByOficinaAndInMarcaResolucion("some oficina", "PE")`.

There is a [working sample including tests demonstrating this on Github](https://github.com/schauder/stackoverflow/tree/main/mongo/mongo-in-with-null).